# Rout is not loading the component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am trying to navigate between **social media** and **company** , but when I hit  company it's component is loading but when i am hitting social media I am getting error

**error I am getting -** 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'social-media'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'social-media'

I am putting detail of code below

**app-routing.module.ts** file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { D7socialMediaComponent } from './d7social-media/d7social-media.component';
import { CompanyComponent } from './company/company.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'social-media' , component: D7socialMediaComponent},
   {path: 'company' , component: CompanyComponent},

];
```

***app.component.html***

```
 <nav>
    <a routerLink="/social-media"> Social Media </a>
    <a routerLink="/company"> Company </a>
    </nav>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

***d7social-media.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-d7social-media',
  templateUrl: './d7social-media.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./d7social-media.component.css']
})
export class D7socialMediaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app-routing.module add:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
...

    imports: [
            CommonModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ]
```

change your app module to:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { D7socialMediaComponent } from './d7social-media/d7social-media.component';
import { CompanyComponent } from './company/company.component';

export const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'social-media' , component: D7socialMediaComponent},
  {path: 'company' , component: CompanyComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes) 
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I am using Angular 6 and I have put this code into **app-routing.module.ts**
so after I Import RouterModule into my page how I can use it

Comment: in your app-routing.module import ```RouterModule``` then again in your app-routing.module in your imports add ```RouterModule.forRoot(routes)```

Comment: for example check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing)

Comment: thanks , I have did that RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
I am getting error with routes 
error ->
[ts] Block-scoped variable 'routes' used before its declaration.

Comment: but you should accept my answer not another one, i answered it first and i was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to declare `routes` with **RouterModule** in **imports** array and if you are using lazyModule concept then need to declare route with **RouterModule.forChild(routes)**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { D7socialMediaComponent } from './d7social-media/d7social-media.component';
    import { CompanyComponent } from './company/company.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
         {path: 'social-media' , component: D7socialMediaComponent},
         {path: 'company' , component: CompanyComponent},
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ppRoutes)
      ],
      declarations: []
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket Avhad . you are Rockstar